# Gremlin python return edges with all properties

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm using gremlin Python to query a Neptune DB. Given a vertices, I need to return all the outward edges with their 'from' and 'to' ids, label and any other properties.

The query below

```
query_result = g.V().has('name', 'marco').outE().inV().path().toList()
```

gives me the 'from' and 'to' in a form i can parse into a list of dicts, and a value map of the  edge gives me the other values but i need it returned in a single list. my ideal format is [{from: x, to: y, label: foo, property1: bar},...]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `elementMap` step:

```
g.V().has('name', 'marko').outE().inV().
  path().
    by(elementMap())
```

EDIT:

if `elementMap` not supported you can specify what you want to get from vertices and edges separately using `by` steps. there you can create any data format you want with `project`

```
g.V().has('name', 'marko').outE().inV().
  path().
    by(valueMap(true)).by(union(
      project('from', 'to').
        by(outV().id()).
        by(inV().id()),
      valueMap(true)
    ).unfold().
    group().by(keys).
      by(select(values).unfold()))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ab

Comment: I've looked at elementMap (or __.elementMap() as is the case in Gremlin Python but I "get 'elementMap' is not defined".  Is there a specific import i need maybe?

Also, thanks for pointing me to gremlify, it will be super helpful.

Comment: elementMap() was introduced in TinkerPop 3.4.4.  Presently, Neptune only supports up through TinkerPop 3.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

You can get almost the result you need by simply projecting the results. I will add an example at the end of how to flatten it even more. You should be able to tweak this query any way you need adding more `valueMap` steps etc. This does not yield a single list but groups each edge with its properties, label and ID.

Note that I used `valueMap(true)` which is deprecated and the new form is `valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)`. Either will still work currently. The advantage of this approach is that no tracking of the `path` is needed which in general is more efficient in terms of memory usage etc. by the query engine.

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]

gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]

gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').
               outE().
               project('from','edge','to').
                 by(outV()).
                 by(valueMap(true)).
                 by(inV())

==>[from:v[1],edge:[id:9,label:created,weight:0.4],to:v[3]]
==>[from:v[1],edge:[id:7,label:knows,weight:0.5],to:v[2]]
==>[from:v[1],edge:[id:8,label:knows,weight:1.0],to:v[4]]
```

If you want to flatten this result into a single list you can just add a little more to the query:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').
               outE().
               project('from','edge','to').
                 by(outV()).
                 by(valueMap(true)).
                 by(inV()).
               union(select('edge').unfold(),
                     project('from').by(select('from')).unfold(),
                     project('to').by(select('to')).unfold()).fold()   


[id=9,label=created,weight=0.4,from=v[1],to=v[3],id=7,label=knows,weight=0.5,from=v[1],to=v[2],id=8,label=knows,weight
=1.0,from=v[1],to=v[4]]
```

Lastly if you wanted a series of such lists back rather than one big one you can wrap the `union` step in `local` scope.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').
               outE().
               project('from','edge','to').
                 by(outV()).
                 by(valueMap(true)).
                 by(inV()).local(
               union(select('edge').unfold(),
                     project('from').by(select('from')).unfold(),
                     project('to').by(select('to')).unfold()).fold())      

==>[id=9,label=created,weight=0.4,from=v[1],to=v[3]]
==>[id=7,label=knows,weight=0.5,from=v[1],to=v[2]]
==>[id=8,label=knows,weight=1.0,from=v[1],to=v[4]]
```